# How to specify path with ImageIO write in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, file-io, nullpointerexception, filepath, javax.imageio

I have a JavaFX program in which the user may choose a profile picture.  This profile picture is applied and should then be saved to a resources folder at the same level as my bin and src folders.  I have a few questions:

- How do you define the file path?  This is my current attempt.  I get a NullPointerException, but I think that has something to do with the output stream.  It's fixable, so I am mostly worried about the path.  This works when accessing an image, so why doesn't it work when saving one?

```java
// Store chosen profile picture
File outputFile = new File("/resources/profilePicture.png");
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(croppedProfilePicture, null), "png", outputFile);
```

- When I go to deploy the application, will I get issues with saving to a resource folder at the same level as bin and src?  Do bin and src even exist when you deploy an application?

Thanks.  I can supply any more information if needed.

Comment: Resources are—or at least _should_ be—read only. Also, that path will likely either resolve to `<root-of-filesystem>/resources/...` or `<working-directory>/resources/...`

Comment: That's helpful.  Resources is just a folder that I made to store the image.  If not resources, do you have any suggestions for where to save a user's profile pic?  Thanks.

Comment: Note, by "resources" I mean files embedded in your application (i.e. part of the JAR file), so if the `resources` directory is some external directory for holding data then those files can be written to. The difficulty is having a reliable place to put, and later find, your application data directory. I've seen a lot of apps create a (possibly hidden) directory under the user's home directory. On Windows there's `%[LOCAL]APPDATA%`. You might even want to change locations depending on the OS. This may help: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23040/.

Comment: Interesting, so to get this external folder holding the files, I assume my program would need to include code which creates the folder?  Besides that, I think that is all.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also consider `java.util.prefs.Preferences` to store user choices.

Comment: If you post a question about an exception, *always* include the full stack trace. Also, indicate which line in your code the exception occurs on. The fact that you get a `NullPointerException` indicates that this is *not* related to the path, as `new File(...)` does not care if the file exists or not. More likely, `croppedProfilePicture` is `null`, or `fromFXImage` returns `null`. But the stack trace would reveal more. That said, the path may still be incorrect...

Comment: @haraldk I will definitely do that in the future.  I changed it to a full path using `System.getProperty("user.home")` to identify  the user directory and then added on my directory.  I took Slaw's recommendation and made my application create a sort of AppData outside of the project directory.